# Process for reducing calculations to their simplest form

Tags: arithmetic

I have the following formula which I suspect I may be able to reduce further but I haven't found a way yet. Is there is method I can follow to ensure that I have reached the simplest form possible?

$$\sqrt{1 - \frac{2 - \sqrt{2}}{4}}$$

Generally when I go to reduce something I just play around with the numbers until my brain, through some process unknown to me, realizes that something can be simplified by doing XYZ thing. For example:

$$\sqrt{\Bigg(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\Bigg)^2 + \Bigg(1 - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\Bigg)^2}$$
$$\sqrt{\Bigg(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{4}}\Bigg)^2 + \Bigg(1 - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\Bigg)\Bigg(1 - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\Bigg)}$$
$$\sqrt{\frac{2}{4} + 1 - 2\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} + \frac{2}{4}}$$
$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{2} + 1 - \sqrt{2} + \frac{1}{2}}$$
$$\sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2}}$$

The question again:

Is there is method I can follow to ensure that I have reached the simplest form possible?

Basically, is there a way to make sure that I have covered all the bases?

Comment: The first thing you should ask yourself is what makes an expression simpler than another expression.

Comment: The smallest number of figures while still in exact form.